# How should I instantiate List<List<String>> in Java

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
            List<List<String>> allData= getData()
            
            if (allData== null)
                allData= new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
            // populate allData below
```

Now I want to initialize `allData` but I get `Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> to List<List<String>>`. What is the correct way I can initialize this?

It is not possible to return `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` from `getData()`

Thanks!

Comment: `allData = new ArrayList<List<String>>();` or - even simpler - let type inference do its job: `allData = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do it very simply:

```
allData = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you can add new lists to allData:

```
List innerList = new ArrayList<>();
innerList.add("some string");
// .... etc ...
allData.add(innerList);
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot redefine the generic type of the reference when you instantiate the concrete implementation.  The reference is `List<List<String>>` so the assigned `List` must be capable of accepting any `List<String>` as an element.  When you instantiated your instance, you attempted to limit this to `ArrayList<String>`.

The explicit solution is:

```
allData = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

or more simply as:

```
allData = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Nice explanation. Plus one to this answer

Answer (score 1):

```
A simple example of getData might be as below -
        
   public static List<List<String>> getData(String fileName){
        List<List<String>> content = null;
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName ))) {
            content = lines
                    .map(l -> l.split(" "))
                    .map(Arrays::asList)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content;
    }
```